# swift Non-void function should return a value in a guard let

Tags: ios, swift

```
    guard let cell = tableView
        .dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as? FolderAndFileCell else {
        print("some")
        return
    }
```

It says that

> Non-void function should return a value

What should I return here?

Comment: What does the outer function tell you to return?

Comment: It tells me to return 'UITableViewCell'

Comment: Don’t use guard here. Just force cast and let it crash if it’s wrong because that would be a programming issue you need to fix.

Comment: You can also use a call to `fatalError("message")` in lieu of a return for unexpected errors that you **want** to crash with a console message telling you why you crashed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inside `cellForRowAt` you have to

```
guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as? FolderAndFileCell else {
    print("some")
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

This signature

> func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
>     cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

should has a non void return value

---

The well-know approach is

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as! FolderAndFileCell
```

Comment: The problem with a solution like this is that it hides the actual problem. Let it crash so it can fixed quicker.

Comment: @rmaddy i agree , but if this happen it'll show in testing at least the first time and the op will fix it . won't it ??

Comment: Returning an empty cell instead of crashing makes it less obvious what the problem is. The dev will see empty cells and wonder why. Is it the failed guard? Is it a problem with the custom cell?  A crash is clear.

Comment: I should write the first block to clarify the reason to the op  , plus he has a print inside the guard return which will make him know if the cells are empty , + i added the correct way end of answer , also on what basis did you assume that the op should has a wrong table registration that will give a problem ?

Answer (score 0):

This is an instance where you should be doing this instead.

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as! FolderAndFileCell
```

You shouldn't need to use guard because I assume you are wanting to set the cell to `FolderAndFileCell`. If you can't set the cell to that, and go ahead and return a `UITableViewCell()` you are going to just get an empty cell and not know the reasoning.

I suggest you force cast to `FolderAndFileCell` and deal with the error if it presents then simply returning an empty cell if an error setting the cell is present.